# How do I copy elements of an array based on elements of another array?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
pop=np.zeros((population_size,chromosome_length))
for i in range(population_size):
    for j in range(i,chromosome_length):
        pop[i,j] = random.randint(0, 1)        
pop

array([[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

I have another array `expected`, generated from un-shown code, with an example below:

```
array([[1.99214608],
       [1.45140389],
       [0.07068525],
       [0.69507167],
       [1.08384057],
       [0.70685254]])
```

I then want to bin the values of `expected` based on custom intervals:

```
actual=np.zeros((population_size,1))
for i in range(len(expected)):
    if expected[i]>=1.5:
        actual[i]=2
    elif 1.5>expected[i]>=0.9:
        actual[i]=1
    else:
        actual[i]=0
actual=actual.astype(int)   
total_count=int(np.sum(actual))
print(total_count)

[[2]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]]
 4
```

and I want the final output as:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.]])
```

based on the values in `total_count`. The first row of `pop` got copied twice, the second row once and the fifth row once. In short, what I want is repeat/copy/duplicate elements of an array based on the integer element of another array.

Comment: Sorry, what is `expected`? The array at the very bottom of your question?

Comment: No, I can see your code for that part, and it's properly-formatted in your question. I mean where is the variable named `expected` defined?

Comment: the last array is actual

Comment: So where is `expected`? I can't validate any approach unless I can verify against that set input. Please [edit] the question to include it

Comment: Sorry, is that ok?

Comment: Ok, scratch that. Now there are even more unknowns. We need a [mcve] - I don't need the code to _generate_ `expected` if you could just me a representative array so that we can actually run the code. I suggest removing the code that you just added

Comment: Note; thank you for responding to my feedback so far. I recognise it's your first day on the site and it can be daunting. The main thing to remember is that we are not familiar with your problem, so you just need to make it as simple as possible to give us something that we can run by giving a _reproducible_ example. I think I have most of the parts covered for an answer already, but I can't validate anything to be sure it actually works

Comment: Yes, it is my first day. Thank you for your feedback. If my question is clear to you, can you please help me out.

Comment: Where you have `pop` in your question and it shows us that 2D array. You literally just need to do the same with `expected` and include that array in the question. At the moment, it just throws `NameError` because that array doesn't exist in your question before you use it. We don't need to generate `expected`, you just need to show us what it actually is

Comment: I agree with @roganjosh we absolutely need a [minimal reproducible example]. Try to delete as much code as possible while maintaining the part with the problem. Try to make as simple as possible for us to decipher and help you.

Comment: Ok. I've included expected as you said.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Writing up an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try address this question in sections as you are using NumPy arrays as though they are lists, and therefore losing a lot of the purpose of the library in the first place. Although the syntax is much more compact, it comes with significant speed increases.

### Creating the population

This one is simple enough. We can make a direct replacement for generating `pop` by using [`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html?highlight=random%20randint#numpy.random.randint). We need to specify values for `population_size` and `chromosome length` and use those to specify the output size.

```
population_size = 6
chromosome_length = 10

pop = np.random.randint(0, 2, (population_size, chromosome_length))
```

**NOTE**: This won't give the exact same values as you've included in your actual question because we haven't set a seed for the random number generator. However, the code is directly equivalent to your `for` loop but more performant.

### Generating `expected`

I can't make an exact replacement for this section because it's too much to replace your loops, with some variables also being undefined. So, I'm just assuming that I'll get the same 2D array as you have shown:

```
expected = np.array([[1.99214608],
                     [1.45140389],
                     [0.07068525],
                     [0.69507167],
                     [1.08384057],
                     [0.70685254]])
```

### Binning the data

This is a bit more complex. We can make use of [`numpy.digitize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html?highlight=digitize#numpy.digitize) to bin the data between your intervals (0, 0.9 and 1.5). However, this method will not work with 2D arrays so I'm going to use [`numpy.ravel()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html?highlight=digitize#numpy.digitize) to flatten the array first.

This is going to give back a list of bin identities that each value of `expected` belongs to. However, bin identities start at 1, and we want to use these values as *indicies* of an array further on, so I'm also going to subtract 1 from the result at the same time.

```
bins = np.array([0, 0.9, 1.5])
dig = np.digitize(expected.ravel(), bins) - 1
```

### Last Steps

I'm going to create an array of values that correspond to the bin categories. We can then use [`numpy.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html?highlight=take#numpy.take) to replace the values of `dig` with the corresponding replacement values.

```
replacements = np.array([0, 1, 2])
actual = np.take(replacements, dig)
```

And *finally* :), we can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html?highlight=repeat#numpy.repeat) using `actual` to take rows from `pop` in the correct proportions to build the output.

### Final Code

```
import numpy as np

population_size = 6
chromosome_length = 10

pop = np.random.randint(0, 2, (population_size, chromosome_length))

# But I'm going to deliberately overwrite the above to solve your particular case
pop = np.array([[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
                [0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
                [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
                [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])


# Hard-coded :/
expected = np.array([[1.99214608],
                     [1.45140389],
                     [0.07068525],
                     [0.69507167],
                     [1.08384057],
                     [0.70685254]])

bins = np.array([0, 0.9, 1.5])
dig = np.digitize(expected.ravel(), bins) - 1

replacements = np.array([0, 1, 2])
actual = np.take(replacements, dig)

out = np.repeat(pop, actual, axis=0)
print(out)
```

Gives:

```
[[0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Learned a lot :)